How to return longest IPv6 formt when using `ip` command on Linux
When I use the command ip address show eth0 my Centos shows my IPs using this format 2600:5c35:e991:92b::3/64 but I would like it to return in this format 2600:5c35:e991:092b:0000:0000:0003/64 which is the longest one (without anything like ::). Is it possible? This will help me to match these IPs with another IP list which already has all IPv6 in the longest format.
If the ip command does not allow that, do you know a pipe or | that I can use in Linux to convert those IPs to the longest format?
Thank you!

Ir is following RFC 5952 Section_4.2.1. Shorten as Much as Possible: "The use of the symbol "::" MUST be used to its maximum capability. For example, 2001:db8:0:0:0:0:2:1 must be shortened to 2001:db8::2:1. Likewise, 2001:db8::0:1 is not acceptable, because the symbol "::" could have been used to produce a shorter representation 2001:db8::1."

install sipcalc

Modify your other tool to accept IP's in their shortest form?

Install sipcalc, then create the following script (bash)
lets call it full6.sh
#!/bin/bash
doit() {
    LINE="$1"
    IFS='/ ' read -r -a array <<< "$LINE"
    IP="${array[1]}"
    FULL=$(sipcalc $IP | grep "Expanded" | cut -d ' ' -f 3)
    echo "${LINE/$IP/$FULL}"
}
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line == *" inet6 "* ]]; then
        doit "$line"
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
done

then you can simply
ip address show eth0 | bash full6.sh

